# Can you identify these 4 minifigs?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me identify these last 4 minifigs.

Comment: FFS, Goldie, that's 9 minifig ident requests in the last 8 hours. Plz learn to do image searches.

Comment: I tried to search and not sure where to best do so.

Comment: Screenshot, crop torso+legs, search in https://yandex.com/images/ , grab minifig name, search on bricklink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First is [sw0603 "Shadow stormtrooper"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0603), with Lord Business' hair (from The Lego Movie).

Second one is [sw0258 "Hoth officer"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0258), possibly with a different head.

Third one is [loc002 "Razcal](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=loc002) from the Legends of Chima line.

Fourth one is [sw0581 "AT-AT driver"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0581).